# BigQuery handling dependencies and retries in query scheduling

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm looking for some best (simplest;)) practices here.
I have Google Analytics data that is send to BigQuery on a daily basis. I have a query running on a daily basis that uses the data from the previous day's table.
However, I can't be sure this table and the data is there at the time the query runs and I'd like to check if it does. If it isn't there I want to retry later.
Ideally I have some monitoring/alerting around this as well.

Of course this can be done within the Google Cloud in many ways, I'm looking for some best practices how others do this?
I'm used to working with Airflow, but using Composer just for this seems a bit over the top. Cloud Run would be an option and I'm sure there are others. Also I've seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64700940/running-dependent-scheduled-queries-in-bq) discussing how to handle a dependency in SQL, I'm just not sure if I could have it retry using just SQL as well?

EDIT:
I've got the check for the table working in SQL. I guess I just have to see if BigQuery has a way to build in delay like 'WAITFOR'

Comment: Why do you want to be sure the table is here? If there's no rows for that day, you'll get nothing.

Comment: because the table will be there later that day... Google doesn't guarantee the table to be there at a given time

Comment: Please, provide the example table name. Does it contain any date/timestamp part?

Comment: yes... so I'm using the current date (-1 day) to construct the table name. 
But checking if the table is already there is not the problem/challenge. I'm looking for a way to retry with a delay. for instance check again in 30 minutes, rather than continuously checking

Comment: @Chrisvdberge You can [reschedule tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55781118/how-to-automatically-reschedule-airflow-tasks) in airflow using exponential backoff.

Comment: @AnkurSaxena Yeah I know that would be a great option. But using Cloud Composer (which needs to run 24/7 right?) seems a bit of overkill to me ;) 
looking at a different setup now; using Log Monitoring for the table load, trigger pub/sub and use a cloud Function to listen to that.